# Internet Connection Problem in Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, 14.04, internet

I had Ubuntu 12.04 previously installed on my Laptop and i was having problems in connecting to internet (I was connecting to Wifi), and Chrome and Firefox both showed "Connection to Server lost", and when i tried updating through terminal it was also not able to connect to internet, but my bittorrent client was connecting fine to Wifi internet connection. So i installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 7 and i'm having same problem in it also.

Also if i try disconnecting to Wifi and connect again, internet works fine for 5-10 minutes but then again it starts giving error. Also, there is no problem in internet connection as it is working fine with my Android Device and Windows 7.

Here is some of my `lspci -v` output:
 [image: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adaptor - kernel driver atk9k]

The full output can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cNjO.png).

The script output can be found [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7866574/).

Comment: What wifi card are you using? - please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/502644/edit) your question and add the output of `lspci -v` - using [formatting](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Other two screenshots :

snap3 : http://imgur.com/O3TFDzi

snap4 : http://imgur.com/6ZQwveX

Answer (score 1):

Please do:

```
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv ath9k
sudo modprobe -v ath9k
```

First in your router change `802.11bgn` to `802.11bg`.

Second change the wep encryption to just wpa2 (CCMP)(AES) not (TKIP) if you have that option it will work best.

Third set your wireless channel in the router to 1 or 11 then save the router configuration and reboot it.

Fourth go into network manager at top right corner of the screen and click on edit connections>wireless tab and set IPV6 to ignore and change your dns server to google according to the screenshots.
[image: DNS Settings][image: IPV6 Setting]

Then reboot.

Comment: I can't connect to my wifi network now. :( It got disconnected by this command !!

Comment: Did you copy and paste for accuracy? did you run the code one line at a time? did you run the third command?

Comment: Yes i did. I restarted the system and till now it's working fine.
Thanks.
Can you give me some rough idea what this command did?

Comment: This command change the encryption from being controlled by  hardware to being controlled by software. Please accept the answer so everyone will benefit from it.

Comment: I'm having those problems again. And i'm also sometimes not able to connect to wifi network like i said earlier.

It gives [this](http://i.imgur.com/YPc9K0h.png?1) error !!

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue. http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do

Comment: Here is the wireless info :

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7866574/

Comment: I updated my answer. What country are you in? the country code may be wrong.

Comment: I was on the third step, when i saved the router settings, it showed "server not found" and since then i can not connect to my wifi network from any of my device(not even from my android phone). Even when i'm entering correct password, it says authentication failed !!

Comment: Go into network manager top right corner of the screen click on edit connection>wireless>wireless security and choose wpa/wpa2 security then close and reboot.

Comment: It is already on WPA & WPA2 Personal.
But i can't connect my other devices to the wifi network also.

Comment: My laptop is down and I am posting from windows, so I will be unavailable until I get ubuntu fixed.  Reset your router and see if that fixes the other devices not being able to connect. Sounds like it may be going out.